# Ignoring Maven/Scala unit test files

Tags: scala, unit-testing, maven-2

I am writing my unit test cases for a Java project using Scala (JUnit 4). I am running the tests using Maven.

I have written a `src/test/scala/com.xxx.BaseTest` class for the tests to provide some common functionality (`@BeforeClass`, etc.), but no actual `@Test` cases.

Whenever I run the tests using `mvn` on the command line, it insists on trying to look for tests in the `BaseTest` class, and gets an error because there are none present.

Other than using an `@Ignore`, is there any way to have Maven/Scala/Surefire not try to run the `BaseTest` class? Adding the `@Ignore` is not a big deal, but my test run shows one more test than I actually have with the label "Skipped: 1".

**UPDATE**: I found a solution. I renamed `BaseTest` to `Base`; Maven now ignores it. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either rename the base test class not to have *Test ending, for example `BaseTestCase.java`. This is what I would recommend.

Most likely maven executes tests with [surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/), so alternatively you just can configure surefire plugin to skip BaseTest.java. I think, by default surefire assumes that all classes ending with `*Test` are test classes. Something like this in the `pom.xml`.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/BaseTest.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: I tried the second suggestion and id did not work. Maybe something to do with it being a Scala test file.